# Is there a way to reference a security group from a previous Cloudformation stack in a new CF stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to build a stack with multiple EC2 instances that have varied security groups.

It would be easy for me if I could create my security groups in advance and reference them in my EC2 stack.

Is there a way to reference an existing security group resource in a CF stack?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

yes this is totally possible with standard Cloudformation templates. 
You can solve this in a couple of ways.

If you are using nested stacks, you can create all the security groups you need in one sub-stack. That stack should have Outputs for each of the Security Group Ids you created.

```
Outputs:
  SecurityGroup1Id:
    Description: Security Group 1 ID
    Value: !Ref SecurityGroup1
```

In the stack that then creates your EC2 instances, you can define [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#aws-specific-parameter-types) for each of the security Groups. It can either be an array or one parameter for each Group, depending on your use case.

**Single Template**

If the EC2 instances and security groups are being defined in the same template, then you can use a simple Ref to access the ID of the already created security group. ie:  `!Ref SecurityGroup1Name`

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a security group deployed and you know the Id of it you can reference it like this under Properties.

You can reference multiple security groups, as it is a list

```
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - <the id of the security group>
        - <another security group ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cross reference outputs from a stack in another.

Here is a walkthrough from the AWS official documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-crossstackref.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html

Answer (score 0):

If the Security Groups were created outside of CloudFormation (Console/CLI) or the CloudFormation stacks aren't linked via [nesting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html) or [exports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html), you should define them as Parameters, then reference that parameter name in your template:

```
Parameters:
  MySecurityGroup: 
    Type: String
    Description: ID of an existing VPC security group (sg-xxxxxx)

Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      # All of your other properties
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref MySecurityGroup
```

If the security group ID is something you're going to reference often, put it in SSM Parameter Store and link the two by following the steps in this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/integrating-aws-cloudformation-with-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm getting the following error:

 The following resource(s) failed to create: [MyInstance]. . Rollback requested by user
When specifying a security group you must specify a group id for each item

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a security group in advance and refer them into the new stack.
In the below example we are creating a securty group through cloudformation template to allowing 3389/RDP Protocol for user(user name is User1) and exporting security group
name.

And in EC2 CloudFormation stack we are importing the exported value(sg name) of security group CloudFormation stack.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: CloudFormation template for Security Group definitions
Parameters:
    User1:
      Description: Public IP OF Deven .
      Type: String
      Default: 106.209.184.29/32
      AllowedPattern: (\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/(\d{1,2})
      ConstraintDescription: Must be valid IP Range.

Resources:
  MySG:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Common Jenkins SG.
      VpcId: vpc-8587d522
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3389
          ToPort: 3389
          CidrIp: !Ref User1
          Description: User1 - RDP access  .
        - Key: Name
          Value: test-security-group
      SecurityGroupEgress: []

Outputs:
  Ec2SecurityGroup:
    Description: Security Group ID for EC2
    Value: !Ref MySG
    Export:
      Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-testapplication"
```

In Youe EC2 instance template import the value . below is the example for the same.

```
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
          .
          .
   (your other parameters mentioned in 'AWS::EC2::Instance' )
          .
          .
      KeyName: !Ref Key
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
      SecurityGroups:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          !Sub "${SGStackName}-RenderEngine" ##### SGStackName is Security group CloudFormation Stack name 
          .
          .
   (your other parameters mentioned in 'AWS::EC2::Instance' )
          .
          .
```

For more detail please gough with official [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)